# Prove sum of subspaces is the smallest containing subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that it takes three steps:

- $U_1+...+U_m$ is a vector space
- $U_1,...,U_m  \subset U_1+...+U_m$
- $U_1+...+U_m \subset U_1,...,U_m$

I know how to prove point 1. And point 2 is OK since the sum must contain all its elements.

The problem is point 3. How to see that $U_1+...+U_m \subset U_1,...,U_m$

Comment: What is $V$ in this stuff?

Comment: @Bernard is it better now?

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove point $3$: it is false in general (except if all $U_i$s are contained in one of them).

Actually what remains to prove  is that if a subspace $V$ contains $U_1,\dots,U_m$, it contains their sum
$$U_1+\dots+U_m=\bigl\{u_1+\dots+u_m\mid \forall i=1,\dots, m,\;u_i\in U_i\bigr\}.$$
This is clear, since if each $u_i\in U_i$, it also belongs to $V$, which is a subspace, so their sum belongs to $V$. This proves that
$$U_1+\dots+U_m\subset V.$$